# What's the cross product in 2 dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The math book i'm using states that the cross product for two vectors is defined over $R^3$:

$$u = (a,b,c)$$
$$v = (d,e,f)$$

is:

$$u \times v = \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

and the direction of the resultant is determined by curling fingers from vector v to u with thumb pointing in direction of the cross product of u x v.

---

Out of curiosity, what's the cross product if u and v are defined over $R^2$ instead of $R^3$ instead:

$$u = (a,b)$$
$$v = (d,e)$$

Is there a "degenerate" case for the cross product of $R^2$ instead $R^3$?  like this is some type of 2x2 determinant instead?

for instance if had a parameterization:

$$\Phi(u,\ v) = (\ f(u),\ \ g(v)\ )$$

and needed to calculate in $R^2$:

$$
D = \Bigg| \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{u}} \times \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{v}} \Bigg|
$$

There are plenty of examples in the book for calculating the determinate D in $R^3$ but none at all for $R^2$ case.

As in:

$$
\iint_{V} f(x,y) dx\ dy = \iint_{Q} f(\Phi(u,v) \Bigg| \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{u}} \times \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{v}} \Bigg|
$$

$$
\Phi(u,v)=(2u \cos v,\ \ u \sin v)
$$

Comment: Point for you to ponder on - the cross product of two vectors gives a third vector, perpendicular to the original two vectors. Could you define a (meaningful) cross product in R^2 that would imitate that property?
Moreover, there are similar threads to this one in MSE, I recommend you to try reading some of them :)

Comment: mean is in th last integral listed above... I have a parameterization defined over R^2... wondering what this degenerates to when taking R^3 formula and applying it to R^2 case...

Comment: for example, maybe we pretend there's a 3 dimension there when we need it to perform the cross product?

Comment: You can consider the "cross product" of a single vector $(a,b)$ to be the vector $(-b,a)$ perpendicular to it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider the two vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ to have $z$-co-ordinate $0$, so that their "cross product" would be $(0,0,k)$ for some $k$. But it really depends on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

In $n$ dimensions, the Levi-Civita symbol has $n$ indices, two of which contract with those of two vectors whose wedge product is sought in the geometry's exterior algebra. This obtains an object with $n-2$ indices, so whereas [we get a familiar vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Cross_and_triple_products) if $n=3$, we get a scalar if $n=2$. In particular, $\binom{a}{b}\land\binom{c}{d}=ad-bc$.

Comment: Great answer! I learned something new.

Answer (score 4):

The cross product in **2 dimensions** is a **scalar** give my a 2x2 determinant:

$$
(a, b) \times (c, d) = \begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{vmatrix} = ad - cb
$$

The cross product in **3 dimensions** is a **vector** given by the 3x3 determinant:

$$
(a, b, c) \times (d, e, f) = \begin{vmatrix}
e_x & e_y & e_z \\
a   & b   & c   \\
d   & e   & f   \\
\end{vmatrix} 
$$

---

E. A. Abbott describes a 2D cross product nicely in his mathematical fantasy book "Flatland":

Flatland describes life and customs of people in a 2-D world: in this universe vectors can be summed together and projected, areas are calculated, rotations are clock-wise or counter clock-wise, reﬂection is possible... *but **cross product** does not exist; otherwise, 2-D inhabitants should have great fantasy to imagine a 3rd dimension to contain a vector orthogonal to their plane.*

By the way, in 2-D a single scalar number is sufficient to describe a force’s moment.

$$
M(\vec{r}, \vec{F}) = r_1 F_2 - r_2 F_2 
$$

With such a deﬁnition, this operation respects all algebraic properties of cross product, but the result is a scalar.

[image: flatland]